# Add Textbox in material ui select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I m trying to add a text box in material ui select option but on changing text in text box i want to stop key navigation because on pressing alphabets key it is navigating to option starting with that alphabet
Here is my code and picture of which i m trying to achieve
[image]

```
<Select
            className={className}
            style={style}
            open={open}
            value={value}
            error={error}
            onChange={props.onChange}
            labelWidth={labelWidth}
            autoWidth={true}
            disabled={disabled}
            inputProps={{ helperText: helperText }}
            MenuProps={{
              classes: {
                root: "menu-item"
              }
            }}
            classes={{
              disabled: 'editable',
              select: 'selected-item'
            }}
          >
            {
              <form>
                  <TextField
                    style={{ width: "150px" }}
                    onChange={(event) => handleChange(event)}
                    error={validation.isTextInValid}
                    onClick={
                      event => {
                        event.stopPropagation();
                      }
                    }
                    value={text}
                    label="Add New"
                    InputProps={{
                      endAdornment: (
                        <InputAdornment>
                          <div className="d-flex">
                            <IconButton
                              type="submit"
                              size="sm"
                              onClick={event => {
                                event.stopPropagation();
                                add()
                              }}
                            >
                              <i className="fa fa-plus"></i>
                            </IconButton>
                          </div>
                        </InputAdornment>
                      ),
                    }}
                  />
                </form>

            }
            {props.children}
          </Select>
```

Comment: So when you are clicking on the Add New, and when you type M it goes to Men Accessories ? Is that whats the issue ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS when i type M it goes to men accessories

Comment: Can you create a minimum reproducable code in codesandbox and share the link it will be helpful

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Ok

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/currying-butterfly-ikujy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @RyanCogswell thanks men this thing wasted my whole day